what is proper workflow for modeling huge structure
main goal
I'm currently working on my hobby project to recreate colleage building.
And my main goal is to make real size building and export it to unreal engine so that player can enter the building and walk inside it.
the building is composed of three big lecture room parts and one long part that connect all of them
problems

UV for such building is too large that baking texture is impossible

Since many of materials i used is procedural material I have to bake them to export to unreal
Aside other minor problems that i have to bake for over 10 procedural material just for one part and horrible computer performance can bake no more than 2048 by 2048 pixels, Each faces of UVmap are so gigantic and overlaped to each other proper baking is impossible.
I know smart UV unwrapping can make all faces fits into texture image while unoverlaped, but this solution tend to break alignment which leads to third problems

Doesn't know proper way to make hollow inside for players to walk in

Any mesh in blender has hollow inside, so the method I tried - placing large cubes and other props inside the cube - is an effective way to recreate the scene of a single room.
But it gets tricky when it comes to huge structure with many rooms inside.

alignment of tiled texture is very annoying and time-consuming

Most of building exterior is tiled. metalic tiles, yellow stone tiles, red stone tiles, windows, etc.
Which means just slight off of UVmap make it look terrible.
Smart UV unwrapping can solve this problem in some case but neighboring faces might be detached in UVmap. Which leads to first problem.
Image for context

problem 1

problem 2

problem 3

Possible Solution?
these are few possible solutions I come up with.
mark seam then smart uv unwrap
I don't know much about how UVmap works, I learned that smart uv unwrapping consider marked seams.
It may prevent detachment of neighboring faces, fixing problem 3.
scale the texture
My procedural textures are 5x5 tiles so normal sized UV draw gigantic tiles.
Instead of scaling UV to fit as much tiles as i want, scaling texture into somthing like 500x500 tiles may fix problem 1.
break down into small units and modularize
Instead of placing every rooms and interior objects into one big box, making modular walls and assembling them like lego blocks seems to be ideal way to construct multiple room inside building.
But even though i was right about this, will it be better assembling in unreal engine? or assemble in blender, join every part, then export?
It's been like 2 weeks of struggling and it's literally destroying my mind. I will appreciate every comment and answer about this question. please help me.

Don't try to make everything in a single monolithic mesh with large unique textures. Break things apart into logical objects, a building may be broken into say floors, or individual rooms. In the game engine case it may be worth having separate interiors and exteriors. Recycle materials for common finishes, use tileable textures shared across objects for common materials, make them seamless and let them repeat over several stories or cover large surfaces. A building is not a character you don't usually need a lot of bespoke textures.

Thank you for your advise. By the way what does it mean separate interior and exterior?  Do I have to make rooms independently, not using walls and floors to 'form' a room?

You don't "have to" see what best fits your particular needs. For performance reasons many game engines use some form of culling or partial loading to avoid having a whole model loaded at once. If you are in a room, the invisible room across the wall needs not be loaded, nor the whole level above and below. You can go from a whole monolithic building down to individual rooms, with many steps in between like a whole level, or even several connected rooms in a single object. The finer your division, the better granular loading you may get, see what your particular engine likes best and adapt.
